# Rotate (3d cube) in IE.10 & IE.11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I want to display a 3d object in Internet Explorer 10 and 11 (Chrome works as intended).

To make it simple I created a Fiddle with my current status.

I browsed the comments on this website and some others and mainly got the feedback that IE.10 and IE.11 requires the perspective setting in each face definition.

I made another Fiddle trying this, yet the base rotation problem still remains in those two browsers.

Both tries have the problem in a 90deg turn, which are getting displayed white in IE.10 and IE.11.

What do I need to change or improve on the first example to get it running correctly in IE.10 and IE.11?

Comment: please check http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d

Comment: Thank you.
I know that it is supported and I found examples for IE.10 and IE.11: - http://codepen.io/dehash/pen/LwIyE

Yet I could not figure out yet what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please do not avoid the requirement to post code along with the jsfiddle by posting a tiny url link instead. You *need* to include the relevant code in the question itself

Comment: [See if this works](http://jsfiddle.net/htrkvbjy/1/)

Comment: Alright, first of sorry for not showing the code in the post. I will do that in future posts.

Your example still has the same problem. The first rotation does not show anything (white) and the second works again.

I am trying a different approach now, yet can not post any progress yet.

Comment: The URLs were broken and removed from your post. Please re-update with actual data and not URL shorteners.